# Strategies for creating "chapters" in a simulation with progression?

Tags: javascript, code-organization

So, I'm not sure how to explain this correctly but it is worth a try anyway. I am training tool that has audio and is around 30 minutes long. The simulation plays audio and the user has to perform a couple tasks to solidify the requirements before the next audio clip would play. Does anyone know any common coding strategies for this type of application that I can do some research on?

My google searches haven't been very helpful thus far so i was looking for some help.

Comment: Sounds like you might be looking for a state machine?

Comment: It looks as though you need a grouped quiz type set up. Each chapter would contain the audio and the tasks. The tasks would be scored accordingly. Depending upon the task score you would either stop (fail), repeat (below pass but not a fail) or continue (above pass level).